# Passing ViewModel data from the view page to the POST method

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a view page that looks like this

```
@model PIC_Program_1._0.Models.ItemViewModel
@using PIC_Program_1._0.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SpecialOrderSummary";
    PIC_Program_1_0Context db = new PIC_Program_1_0Context();
}

<style>
    #tablestyle tr, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        /**/
    }
</style>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    <h2>Special Order Summary </h2>
    <p style="color:red" class="noprint">Please review and verify </p>

    if (Model.Components.Where(n => n.SelectedActionType == PartActionType.Transfer).Count() > 0 || Model.ComponentSubComps.Where(n => n.SelectedActionType == PartActionType.Transfer).Count() > 0 || Model.SubCompSubComps.Where(n => n.SelectedActionType == PartActionType.Transfer).Count() > 0 || Model.Parts.Where(n => n.SelectedActionType == PartActionType.Transfer).Count() > 0 || Model.ComponentParts.Where(n => n.SelectedActionType == PartActionType.Transfer).Count() > 0 || Model.SubCompParts.Where(n => n.SelectedActionType == PartActionType.Transfer).Count() > 0 || Model.SubCompSubCompParts.Where(n => n.SelectedActionType == PartActionType.Transfer).Count() > 0)
    {
        <h3 style="color:blue; text-align:center">
            Transfers
        </h3>
    }
    if (Model.Components.Where(n => n.SelectedActionType == PartActionType.Transfer).Count() > 0 || Model.ComponentSubComps.Where(n => n.SelectedActionType == PartActionType.Transfer).Count() > 0 || Model.SubCompSubComps.Where(n => n.SelectedActionType == PartActionType.Transfer).Count() > 0)
    {
        <h4><b>Components </b></h4>
        <table class="tablestyle" style="width: 100%;">

            <tr>
                <th>
                    IGT Component ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    MFG ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    Component Name
                </th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var comp in Model.Components.Where(n => n.SelectedActionType == PartActionType.Transfer))
            {
                Component c = db.Components.Find(comp.ID);

                <tr>
                    <td> @c.ComponentIDLink</td>
                    <td> @comp.MFGNumber</td>
                    <td> @comp.ComponentName</td>
                </tr>
            }
            @foreach (var comp in Model.ComponentSubComps.Where(n => n.SelectedActionType == PartActionType.Transfer))
            {
                Component c = db.Components.Find(comp.ID);
                <tr>
                    <td> @c.ComponentIDLink</td>
                    <td> @comp.MFGNumber</td>
                    <td> @comp.SubCompName</td>
                </tr>
            }
            @foreach (var comp in Model.SubCompSubComps.Where(n => n.SelectedActionType == PartActionType.Transfer))
            {
                Component component = db.Components.Find(comp.ID);
                <tr>
                    <td> @component.ComponentIDLink</td>
                    <td> @comp.MFGNumber</td>
                    <td> @comp.SubCompName</td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
    }

 <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value=" Confirm " class="btn" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here is my ViewModel

```
public class ItemViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int JobId { get; set; }
        public string ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string MFGNumber { get; set; }
        public IList<ItemPartViewModel> Parts { get; set; }
        public IList<ItemComponentViewModel> Components{ get; set; }
        public IList<ComponentPartViewModel> ComponentParts { get; set; }
        public IList<ComponentSubCompViewModel> ComponentSubComps { get; set; }
        public IList<SubCompPartViewModel> SubCompParts { get; set; }
        public IList<SubCompSubCompViewModel> SubCompSubComps { get; set; }
        public IList<SubCompSubCompPartViewModel> SubCompSubCompParts { get; set; }

    }
```

How can I return this view model back to my POST method? It's just a summary page so there is no user actions on this page so I'm confused as to how I can return this viewmodel data back to the controller after the user clicks on "Confirm".

I know that I can just do this,

```
   for (int i = 0; i < Model.Components.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Components[i].ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Components[i].CompID)
    }
```

And provide a `hiddenFor` for each part but thought that their might be a better and cleaner way to handle it?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: could use a hidden field with object serialized into a json and then on form submit do  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); and send that json?

Comment: Could you expand on your answer a little bit? @LeszekP

Comment: add <input type=hidden name="myData" value="serialized object to escaped json"> Then on post form property=MyData will be of type string, but u can deserialize it into type of ItemViewModel